# What is the outcome of this function?

Tags: c, arduino

What is the outcome of this function?

```
#define __32MX250F128D__
#include <proc/p32mx250f128d.h>
#include <plib.h>

//----------------------------------------------------------
int number = 0;
int value = 0;
int x = 0;
int time = 0;
int analogPort = 5;

//----------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
    ANSELA = 1; // Set Ports A as analog
    ANSELB = 0; // B,C as digital
    ANSELC = 0;

    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1; 
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 0; 
    TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0; 
    TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0; 
    TRISCbits.TRISC9 = 0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC8 = 0; 
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 0; 
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB9 = 0; 
    TRISBbits.TRISB8 = 0; 
    TRISBbits.TRISB7 = 0;  
}

//----------------------------------------------------------
void loop() {
  value = analogRead(analogPort);

  if(value > 500){
    number++;
  }
  if(value < 524){
    number--;
  }
  LATBbits.LATB3 = bitCheck(0,number);
  LATCbits.LATC0 = bitCheck(1,number);
  LATCbits.LATC1 = bitCheck(2,number);
  LATCbits.LATC9 = bitCheck(3,number);
  LATCbits.LATC8 = bitCheck(4,number);
  LATCbits.LATC7 = bitCheck(5,number);
  LATCbits.LATC6 = bitCheck(6,number);
  LATBbits.LATB9 = bitCheck(7,number);
  LATBbits.LATB8 = bitCheck(8,number);
  LATBbits.LATB7 = bitCheck(9,number);
  delay(150);

  x = map(value, 0 ,1023, -15, 15);

  time = (-(pow(2*x,2))+1000);

  delay(time);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------
int bitCheck(int where, int value){

    int result = (value >> where) & 1;

    return result;
}
```

This is the code for a fubarino mini, with 10 leds on it, 
if `value` is higher then `500` then number will get higher,
but which value get assigned to `value` in the `map` function at the end?

I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Could you provide more context to your question, please.

Comment: The `arduino` tag makes it pretty obvious where the function comes from.

Comment: yeah sorry, i posted my whole code

Comment: Clearly, the last function is a bitCheck. The other function is a "loop." It says so right in the name!

Comment: what is getting assigned to value in x = map(value, 0 ,1023, -15, 15);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets `x` to a value from -15 to 15 (inclusive) based on the voltage at pin `analogPort`. 15 means 5 volts and -15 means 0 volts.

This value is then used to set a delay between 100 (-(pow(2*15,2))+1000) and 1000 (-(pow(2*0,2))+1000) since the square of `2*x` and `2*-x` yield the same number.

In other words, 0 volts will cause a 0.1 second delay, 2.5 volts will cause a 1 second delay, and 5 volts will cause a 0.1 second delay.

The `map` function maps one numeric range to another. One could convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit with `map(temp, 0, 100, 32, 212)`.

The `analogRead()` function returns a value from 0 to 1023, so it is mapped to the more useful range of -15 to 15.

Comment: how did you come up with the -2600?

Comment: Oops. I think I miscalculated. Edited. (-(pow(2*15,2))+1000) = (-(pow(30,2))+1000) = (-(900)+1000) = 1000 - 900 = 100.

Comment: I thought so, thank you for the answer!, but what does the 0, 1023 do in the function, that  still dont understand

Comment: thanks for the explanation!